# Transitions on carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First, sorry about my english.

I want to do a slider with transitions like this http://pumamaritimeservices.com/beta/ but with bootstrap, i did before a carousel but i don't know if i can do transitions like the first link.

My new slider is the next: http://pumamaritimeservices.com/beta3/

My code is:

```
<div style="height: 90%;" id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill hidden-xs" style="background-image:url('img/slider/01.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="fill show-xs" style="background-image:url('img/slider/01_corta.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2 class="pull-left"><span style="background-color: #B9A004; padding: 5px 15px;">Cargo Surveys</span><br /><br /><span style="background-color: #B9A004; padding: 5px 15px; font-size: 20px">LEARN MORE</span></h2>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill hidden-xs" style="background-image:url('img/slider/02.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="fill show-xs" style="background-image:url('img/slider/02_corta.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2 class="pull-left"><span style="background-color: #012540; padding: 5px 15px;">Containers and Cargo in Containers Surveys</span><br /><br /><span style="background-color: #012540; padding: 5px 15px; font-size: 20px;">LEARN MORE</span></h2>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill hidden-xs" style="background-image:url('img/slider/03.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="fill show-xs" style="background-image:url('img/slider/03_corta.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2 class="pull-left"><span style="background-color: #B81818; padding: 5px 15px;">More than 680 Lloyd’s Agents around the world</span></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Can I do any transition in my existing slider? I really need help with this, i don't want the tipical fade in and fade out, i want enter the image at the left and the text too, and it out at right

Answer (score 1):

you can find more examples and tutorial from this links.

[tutorialrepublic](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php)
and
[mobirise](https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-carousel/)